# Silverstripe adding link after has-one in CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I like the silverstripe CMS, especially the way how you can navigate through it when a dataobject has a 1-n or n-m relationship. However, I also like to navigate from 1-1 or n-1 relations (otherwise know as the has-ones :).

Now I have changed this field in such a way that I can show a link after the has-one dropdown, but I am still not able to point that link to the edit page of the dataobject referenced in the has-one. I can of course create a link manually (and I did), but this is not really a generic solution.

Is there a simple way to get the link to the edit screen of the dataobject in the CMS?

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Comment: From what I understand you saying, one thing to be careful of with is a potentional recursion problem. You go from a N-1, then from the 1 to one of its 1-N relationships, then back to the same 1 from one of those N's etc etc. Could cause some technical issues but more to the point, would be very confusing navigating back out of that.

Comment: I'd start with https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-quickaddnew and add the option to edit as well as add - this should be (in theory) just creating the same from but populated with data and the ID

Comment: Thanks for your responses. About recursion @Tumerj: I am less concerned with the breadcrumb path. It could just replace the current path with the new path, without keeping track of the navigation history

Comment: @barry I do not need a pop up, as the forms can be quite extensive, and I like to be able to navigate further from the new location.